# How to use Rand function combined with Union in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to combine a result from 3 select statements that will choose different food names from different food categories. However my table has quite few instances of "foodItems". I need to select only 1 item for each of the select statements and I want it to be done randomly. I'm not quite sure how to achieve that I've tried inserting  `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` at the end of each select statement but MySQL doesn't like it. Can somebody help

```
SELECT foodName
FROM food
WHERE foodCategory_id = 1 OR 2
UNION
SELECT foodName
FROM food
WHERE foodCategory_id = 7 OR 8 OR 9
UNION
SELECT foodName
FROM food
WHERE foodCategory_id = 10 OR 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an outer SQL where the from clause is some sort of temp table like this:

```
 SELECT food_name from (
  SELECT foodName
  FROM food
  WHERE foodCategory_id = 1 OR 2
  ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) a
 UNION
 SELECT food_name from (
  SELECT foodName
  FROM food
  WHERE foodCategory_id = 7 OR 8 OR 9
  ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) b
 UNION
 SELECT food_name from (
  SELECT foodName
  FROM food
  WHERE foodCategory_id = 10 OR 11
  ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) c
```

Comment: I've just tried that and this solution return only 1 item. I need to return 1 food Name for each of the select statement.

Comment: I've just edited my result. The new query should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT foodname FROM food WHERE .. ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Just add whatever WHERE conditions you want to that.

Comment: When I try that it gives me an error "#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY "

Comment: Then you have the UNION in the wrong place.  It goes right before the second and third SELECT.