# Using RAND to select one row from a set of n

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one is **`Venues`**, one is **`Listings`**, `one to many relationship from Venue to Listings`.

Some venues pay to be 'featured', their results get extra features than the venues who do not pay. It is possible that lets say 5 out of 10 venues would pay to be featured. I do not want to display 5 featured and 5 normal, but rather 2 featured and 8 normal. Obviously the chosen 2 should be dynamic.

Currently I have a query like so: (number of columns has been removed for brevity)

```
SELECT V.VenueName FROM Venues V 
INNER JOIN Listings L ON V.VenueID = L.FK_VenueID 
INNER JOIN Type T ON L.FK_ListingTypeID = T.TypeID 
WHERE V.Active = 1 AND L.Active = 1 AND T.TypeID = 1 AND T.Active = 1 AND V.Featured = 1 
AND HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 16 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 16 AND DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(L.StartDate) 
AND DATE(NOW()) <= DATE(L.EndDate) AND L.DayOfWeek LIKE '%Tuesday%' 
AND DATE(L.StartDate) <= '2015-01-14' AND DATE(L.EndDate) >= '2015-01-14'
UNION
SELECT V.VenueName FROM Venues V 
INNER JOIN Listings L ON V.VenueID = L.FK_VenueID 
INNER JOIN Type T ON L.FK_ListingTypeID = T.TypeID 
WHERE V.Active = 1 AND L.Active = 1 AND T.TypeID = 1 AND T.Active = 1 AND V.Featured = 0 
AND HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 16 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 16 AND DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(L.StartDate) 
AND DATE(NOW()) <= DATE(L.EndDate) AND L.DayOfWeek LIKE '%Tuesday%' 
AND DATE(L.StartDate) <= '2015-01-14' AND DATE(L.EndDate) >= '2015-01-14'
```

As you can see the queries are the same except for the **`Featured = 1/Featured = 0`**.

How would I go about altering the first query (above the union) to **`dynamically pick 2 featured rows at random`**? 2 is a limit, if there is only one matching row in the table then 1 is fine.

Comment: You can use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2.

Comment: Yes. You can check at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701123/how-to-use-rand-function-combined-with-union-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use

```
SELECT VenueName from (
   SELECT V.VenueName FROM Venues V 
   INNER JOIN Listings L ON V.VenueID = L.FK_VenueID 
   INNER JOIN Type T ON L.FK_ListingTypeID = T.TypeID 
   WHERE V.Active = 1 AND L.Active = 1 AND T.TypeID = 1 AND T.Active = 1 AND V.Featured = 1  
   AND HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 16 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 16 AND DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(L.StartDate) 
   AND DATE(NOW()) <= DATE(L.EndDate) AND L.DayOfWeek LIKE '%Tuesday%' 
   AND DATE(L.StartDate) <= '2015-01-14' AND DATE(L.EndDate) >= '2015-01-14'
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2.) a
UNION
SELECT VenueName from (
   SELECT V.VenueName FROM Venues V 
   INNER JOIN Listings L ON V.VenueID = L.FK_VenueID 
   INNER JOIN Type T ON L.FK_ListingTypeID = T.TypeID 
   WHERE V.Active = 1 AND L.Active = 1 AND T.TypeID = 1 AND T.Active = 1 AND V.Featured = 0 
   AND HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 16 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 16 AND DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(L.StartDate) 
   AND DATE(NOW()) <= DATE(L.EndDate) AND L.DayOfWeek LIKE '%Tuesday%' 
   AND DATE(L.StartDate) <= '2015-01-14' AND DATE(L.EndDate) >= '2015-01-14') b
```

Reference: [Union with Rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701123/how-to-use-rand-function-combined-with-union-in-mysql)

Comment: I used a variation of this. Note that I still wanted any featured rows which were left behind by the LIMIT command to be returned in the second SELECT, so I removed the Featured = 0 clause and let the UNION handle it.